# How to connect a web-api to multiple applications

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-web-api

I have a main server with an web-api on it and I need to conect to multiple applications. The problem is,each application has its own server and i can’t put the web-api on each one of them I have to use the main server to host the web-api.Is this even possible to make? I've tried to find a solution but I don't see to find any.
  If more information is necessary I can provide here.

Thank you!

Comment: you got it the other way around, the API is in one place and all the apps connect to the same API.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, one applications can use many web-api. Only need just need to be visible, to be able to connect by the URL.